# Sprout Email PHP Warning

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

Trying out Sprout Email on a fresh local (MAMP/PHP 7.1) install, and whenever I try and create a new Notification I get

```
PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
```

in /vendor/barrelstrength/sprout-base-email/src/controllers/NotificationsController.php

Tried a few different PHP versions in case that helps, but same. Anyone experienced this before and got any suggestions? Much appreciated.

Comment: If you're not on the latest please update to the latest to test. Outside of that, this sounds like a bug and is probably better suited for a support ticket: https://github.com/barrelstrength/craft-sprout-email/issues If you could provide the specific version numbers of Craft/Sprout you are using as well as the full stack trace that references the line number of the error, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Ben. Thought I had very latest version of the plugin, but just updated both Craft and plugin, and problem solved!